# iOS RSS feed data fetching : How to get Description / Content of feed

Tags: ios, rss-reader

I have followed this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial#comments

But I also want to get description/content instead of showing its URL in web view.

I tried everything but nothing worked.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in ray wenderlich website, you can get the feed details from `GDataXML's` `GDataXMLElement`. Check the key you are getting for description/content `GDataXMLElement` like:

```
[item valueForChild:@"description"]
```

and save that string in the nsobject class you created to save the rss feed required data. After that you can load html string in the webview and add your custom css styling for the html string if needed. You can load html string in webview using webview's

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

method. Hope my answer helps.